# View InfluxDB Cronograf charts outside local network

Tags: networking, port, portforwarding, influxdb

I've set up InfluxDB and Chronograf to visualize data. I can view the chronograf dashboard locally at localhost:10000, but I'm not able to access it outside my local network.

I've forwarded UDP/TCP port 10000 as I would normally through my home router.  Is there something special going on here?

Answer (score 1):

In order to serve traffic from another machine besides your local host, you'll need to explicitly set the `Bind` address in the Chronograf config. Depending on what platform you're on, this will either be located at `/usr/local/etc/chronograf.toml` (Mac OS X) or `/etc/opt/chronograf/chronograf.toml` (Linux).

By default, it's set to:

```
Bind = "127.0.0.1:10000"
```

Which should be changed to:

```
Bind = "0.0.0.0:10000"
```

Where `0.0.0.0` is all interfaces on the host machine (or you can set it to a specific IP if needed).